# send request body using a decorator in python

Tags: python, django, request, decorator

I have a function in a django project something like this:

```
class my_class():

def post(self, request, id, format=None):
    logger.info(
                ''.join(
                    ["id"+str(request.get('id')),
                     "name"+str(request.get('name')),
                     "grade"+str(request.get('grade'))]
               )
     )
    row = Student(
         id = request.get('id'),
         name = request.get('name'),
         grade = request.get('grade')
    )
    row.save()
```

Now I want to have a decorator(**@logger**) around my this function which logs everything inside (logger.info). i.e I should only add @logger above the function definition and can log all the request body. Can someone help me how can I do this. I am facing problem in sending the request body from `post` to the decorator.

Answer (score 1):

```
def logger(func):
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # log here
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Comment: how can I log the request body here??

Comment: getting the error: `'Student' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: same as you did it before, you have the same request as in view

Comment: yeah did the same but getting ` 'Student' object has no attribute '__getitem__' this item`

Comment: Can you provide more data? Models file etc.

Comment: the error is in logger.info('Id:', request['id']`
TypeError: 'Student' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should suffice, you might want to also read [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845).

```
class Logger(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info(request.GET)
        self.f(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `logger.info(request.GET)` gives this : `<bound method Student.wrap of <Project.views.Student object at 0x111d9a790>>`